# how to get the datetime.date() value from django model?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem in getting the datetime.date() value in my django...
when i trying to get it like this :

```
>>> s = Booking.objects.values('date_select').distinct('date_select').filter(date_select='2011-12-1')
>>> print s
[{'date_select': datetime.date(2011, 12, 1)}]
```

it has the column of date_select, i just only want the datetime.date(2011, 12, 1), do anyone have an idea about it? i also try this one but its not working :

```
>>> s = Booking.objects.values('date_select').distinct('date_select').filter(date_select='2011-12-1')['date_select']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 153, in __getitem__
    raise TypeError
TypeError
>>>
```

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting back a list with one element so you need to do this:

```
s = Booking.objects.values('date_select').distinct('date_select').filter(date_select='2011-12-1')[0]['date_select']
```

Comment: thanks for the response Dmitry, i try it but the result is not 'datetime.date(2011, 12, 1)` ... `>>> s = Booking.objects.values('date_select').distinct('date_select').filter(date_select='2011-12-1')[0]['date_select']
>>> print s
2011-12-01
>>> 
` is there any other option to get only `datetime.date(2011, 12, 1)`  ?

Comment: ok, but you are not getting the error any longer like you posted in the original question.  This is a different issue now.  What does "only 2011-12-01" mean?  What's the type of the value you are getting back?

Comment: ahh i get it ^_^ i try it in my django code, and it works... thanks Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

Dimitry's answer works but it will raise an exception if your query does not return any results at all (because the index will not exist, likely resulting in IndexError exception).

This does the same, but will not error if the query returns empty results:

```
s = Booking.objects.values('date_select').distinct('date_select').filter(date_select='2011-12-1')
if s.count():
    s = s.get()['date_select']
```

Also worth mentioning that if your query returns more than one result, you'll have to adjust the code accordingly.